# How do I make my own package?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I apologize for the broad question, I'll try my best to explain here.

I want to make my own package that can be installed with `apt-get install` and then being able to use its commands once it is installed. I just don't know where to look in order to learn how to do this.
What language should I use? Specifically for creating file structures and writing to files with user inputs as well.

Comment: MacOS has its own packaging system `pkg`; `apt-get` is for Debian-flavored Linux only (other distros use Red Hat's RPM or their own distro's format like `emerge`, `apk`, etc).

Comment: There are tons of package managers for every major platform, you'll probably need to narrow down more specifically to what your distribution(s) requires. There's a nice list here for most platforms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems

Comment: I want to use the software on Ubuntu and MacOS. My goal is just making a simple software that creates file structures and writes files when running a command. I thought both Ubuntu and MacOS used apt-get?

Comment: MacOS typically doesn't install packages like other *nix based systems unless using MacPorts, Homebrew, Fink, etc. and none of those use apt-get. What language is your application written in that you want to distribute?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question. It's probably best suited to askubuntu.com (if there isn't already an answer there) but might also be on topic at [unix.se] or superuser.com

Comment: I made it in python and it does what I want it to do. I just want to know if there's a better way to distribute it other than downloading python + my python file and running it. I'd love to make it just running by a command and distribute it more easily.

Comment: You would likely want to use `pip` as the package manager if it's Python based.

Comment: I still think it's off-topic. However, you might be better looking at something like pyinstaller, or the PiPy repository rather than making an ubuntu package

Answer (score 2):

Read a lot more about [.deb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) packages, e.g. [deb(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/dpkg-dev/deb.5.en.html) (for Debian and Ubuntu). There is [lots](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.building-first-package.html) of documentation about it (e.g. [Packaging](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging) wiki)

Study *existing* packages for inspiration.

Other distributions have different [package managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager), e.g. [rpm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpm_(software)), etc....

<sup>(the evil is in the details, and they vary from one distribution to the next; in some cases, a `.deb`  for Debian is not nicely working on Ubuntu; quite often it does)</sup>

Comment: In the case of `.deb` packages, start with this overview of documentation: https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging One particular thing to pay attention to is that there are a lot of conventions on how a package should behave, which are enumerated/explained in the Debian policy manual(s). Conforming to these helps to make your package easier to use & work more reliably.

Comment: @user268396, at the same time, if you do a package for yourself (in your organization), following the deb policy is not mandatory (although it may help with the long term maintenance...)